# RSS feed basics - just repeatedly overwriting the same file?

Tags: rss

Really simple question here:

For a PHP-driven RSS feed, am I just overwriting the same XML file every time I "publish" a new feed thing? and the syndicates it's registered with will pop in from time to time to check that it's new?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. An RSS reader has the URL of the feed and regularly requests the same URL to check for new content.

Comment: You don't have any guarantee on how often it gets checked. That's decided by the user or their RSS reader. Usually the feed (XML file) should contain all the recent updates, so that when the reader checks the feed it can get all the new ones and ignore the ones it's already seen.

Comment: Ok, so the feed file shouldn't just be one item at a time then? Perhaps something like all items from the last XX hours?

Comment: Yeah, the last N hours or the last N items or something like that.

Comment: *pop* it just clicked for me -- this can be a regular PHP file that just grabs the most recent items from a table based on whatever time constraints I wish, and builds the RSS XML feed on the fly whenever something hits the page. Sheesh, I feel dense. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

that's how it works, a simple single xml rss file that gets polled for changes by rss readers

for scalability there there is [FeedTree: collaborative RSS and Atom delivery](http://www.feedtree.net/) but unlike another well known network program (bittorrent) it hasn't had as much support in readers by default

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, yes. It isn't necessarily a "file" actually stored on disk, but your RSS (or [Atom](http://www.atomenabled.org/)) is just changed to contain the latest items/entries and resides at a particular fixed URL. Clients will fetch it periodically. There are also technologies like [PubSubHubbub](http://code.google.com/p/pubsubhubbub/) and pinging for causing updates to get syndicated closer to real-time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes... BUT! There are ways to make the susbcribers life better and also improve your bandwidth :) Implement the [PubSubHubbub](http://code.google.com/p/pubsubhubbub/) protocol. It will help any application that wants the content of the feed to be notified as soon as it's available. It'es relatively simple to implement on the publisher side as it only involves a ping.